# Pretty-print a NumPy array without scientific notation and with given precision

Tags: python, numpy, pretty-print

How do I print formatted NumPy arrays in a way similar to this:

```
x = 1.23456
print('%.3f' % x)
```

If I want to print the `numpy.ndarray` of floats, it prints several decimals, often in 'scientific' format, which is rather hard to read even for low-dimensional arrays. However, `numpy.ndarray` apparently has to be printed as a string, i.e., with `%s`. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53164538/4999991) also might interest the ones who end up here via google search.

Answer (score 769, accepted):

Use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to set the precision of the output:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(10)
print(x)
# [ 0.07837821  0.48002108  0.41274116  0.82993414  0.77610352  0.1023732
#   0.51303098  0.4617183   0.33487207  0.71162095]

np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(x)
# [ 0.078  0.48   0.413  0.83   0.776  0.102  0.513  0.462  0.335  0.712]
```

And `suppress` suppresses the use of scientific notation for small numbers:

```
y = np.array([1.5e-10, 1.5, 1500])
print(y)
# [  1.500e-10   1.500e+00   1.500e+03]

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
print(y)
# [    0.      1.5  1500. ]
```

---

**To apply print options locally**, using NumPy 1.15.0 or later, you could use the [`numpy.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html) context manager.
For example, inside the `with-suite` `precision=3` and `suppress=True` are set:

```
x = np.random.random(10)
with np.printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True):
    print(x)
    # [ 0.073  0.461  0.689  0.754  0.624  0.901  0.049  0.582  0.557  0.348]
```

But outside the `with-suite` the print options are back to default settings:

```
print(x)    
# [ 0.07334334  0.46132615  0.68935231  0.75379645  0.62424021  0.90115836
#   0.04879837  0.58207504  0.55694118  0.34768638]
```

If you are using an earlier version of NumPy, you can create the context manager
yourself. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def printoptions(*args, **kwargs):
    original = np.get_printoptions()
    np.set_printoptions(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield
    finally: 
        np.set_printoptions(**original)

x = np.random.random(10)
with printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True):
    print(x)
    # [ 0.073  0.461  0.689  0.754  0.624  0.901  0.049  0.582  0.557  0.348]
```

---

**To prevent zeros from being stripped from the end of floats:**

`np.set_printoptions` now has a `formatter` parameter which allows you to specify a format function for each type.

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.3f}'.format})
print(x)
```

which prints

```
[ 0.078  0.480  0.413  0.830  0.776  0.102  0.513  0.462  0.335  0.712]
```

instead of

```
[ 0.078  0.48   0.413  0.83   0.776  0.102  0.513  0.462  0.335  0.712]
```

Comment: is there a means to apply the formatting to only the specific print statement (as opposed to setting a general output format used by *all* print statements)?

Comment: @Hiett: There is no NumPy function to set print options for just one `print`, but you could use a context manager to make something similar. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: your `np.set_printoptions(precision=3)` suppress the end zeros.. how do you get them to display like this `[ 0.078  0.480   0.413  0.830   0.776  0.102  0.513  0.462  0.335  0.712]`?

Comment: @Norfeldt: I've added a way to do this above.

Comment: @unutbu nice! thank you. Is there however a way to avoid the context manager? like `np.set_printoptions(precision=3, strip_zeros=False)` - I don't feel like using a context every time I need a print :)

Comment: You could take code inside the first `if not strip_zeros` statement, and just use that. What I do is put things like the context manager in a `utils.py` file and import it whenever I need it. So it really does not require much typing to get the functionality you want.

Comment: For single use, what about just call set_printoptions(precision = 3, ...) right before your print command and call set_printoptions() ie no argument, return to default, right after your print command

Comment: This works great. As a side note, you can also use `set_printoptions` if you want a string representation and not necessarily use `print`. You can just call `__str__()` of the numpy array instance and you will get the formatted string as per the printoptions you set.

Comment: Creating a decorator might be an overkill every time you want to print. You can use this which is calling __str__ on the array and then printing. suppress_small will suppress the scientific notation.  `print(np.array_str(X, precision=2, suppress_small=True))`

Answer (score 78):

Use [`np.array_str`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html) to apply formatting to only a single print statement. It gives a subset of `np.set_printoptions`'s functionality.

For example:

```
In [27]: x = np.array([[1.1, 0.9, 1e-6]] * 3)

In [28]: print(x)
[[  1.10000000e+00   9.00000000e-01   1.00000000e-06]
 [  1.10000000e+00   9.00000000e-01   1.00000000e-06]
 [  1.10000000e+00   9.00000000e-01   1.00000000e-06]]

In [29]: print(np.array_str(x, precision=2))
[[  1.10e+00   9.00e-01   1.00e-06]
 [  1.10e+00   9.00e-01   1.00e-06]
 [  1.10e+00   9.00e-01   1.00e-06]]

In [30]: print(np.array_str(x, precision=2, suppress_small=True))
[[ 1.1  0.9  0. ]
 [ 1.1  0.9  0. ]
 [ 1.1  0.9  0. ]]
```

Comment: Likely the most simple and efficient option as it doesn't introduce a permanent change in `printoptions`, nor requires a costly loop or a `with` construction. The possibility to format elements should be integrated into numpy directly (can't understand why it is not the case).

Answer (score 46):

Unutbu gave a really complete answer (they got a +1 from me too), but here is a lo-tech alternative:

```
>>> x=np.random.randn(5)
>>> x
array([ 0.25276524,  2.28334499, -1.88221637,  0.69949927,  1.0285625 ])
>>> ['{:.2f}'.format(i) for i in x]
['0.25', '2.28', '-1.88', '0.70', '1.03']
```

As a function (using the `format()` syntax for formatting):

```
def ndprint(a, format_string ='{0:.2f}'):
    print [format_string.format(v,i) for i,v in enumerate(a)]
```

Usage:

```
>>> ndprint(x)
['0.25', '2.28', '-1.88', '0.70', '1.03']

>>> ndprint(x, '{:10.4e}')
['2.5277e-01', '2.2833e+00', '-1.8822e+00', '6.9950e-01', '1.0286e+00']

>>> ndprint(x, '{:.8g}')
['0.25276524', '2.283345', '-1.8822164', '0.69949927', '1.0285625']
```

The index of the array is accessible in the format string:

```
>>> ndprint(x, 'Element[{1:d}]={0:.2f}')
['Element[0]=0.25', 'Element[1]=2.28', 'Element[2]=-1.88', 'Element[3]=0.70', 'Element[4]=1.03']
```

Answer (score 20):

FYI Numpy 1.15 (release date pending) will [include a context manager for setting print options locally](https://github.com/charris/numpy/blob/07543ccbdd5a311811c9f5e7c871b4353f0c6823/doc/release/1.15.0-notes.rst#new-functions). This means that the following will work the same as the corresponding example in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891805/9632900) (by unutbu and Neil G) without having to write your own context manager. E.g., using their example:

```
x = np.random.random(10)
with np.printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True):
    print(x)
    # [ 0.073  0.461  0.689  0.754  0.624  0.901  0.049  0.582  0.557  0.348]
```

Answer (score 17):

The gem that makes it all too easy to obtain the result as a string (in today's numpy versions) is hidden in denis answer:
[`np.array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html#numpy.array2string)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.random.random(10)
>>> np.array2string(x, formatter={'float_kind':'{0:.3f}'.format})
'[0.599 0.847 0.513 0.155 0.844 0.753 0.920 0.797 0.427 0.420]'
```

Comment: This is one of 2 answers that actually delivers on request and doesn't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 11):

Years later, another one is below. But for everyday use I just

```
np.set_printoptions( threshold=20, edgeitems=10, linewidth=140,
    formatter = dict( float = lambda x: "%.3g" % x ))  # float arrays %.3g
```

---

```
''' printf( "... %.3g ... %.1f  ...", arg, arg ... ) for numpy arrays too

Example:
    printf( """ x: %.3g   A: %.1f   s: %s   B: %s """,
                   x,        A,        "str",  B )

If `x` and `A` are numbers, this is like `"format" % (x, A, "str", B)` in python.
If they're numpy arrays, each element is printed in its own format:
    `x`: e.g. [ 1.23 1.23e-6 ... ]  3 digits
    `A`: [ [ 1 digit after the decimal point ... ] ... ]
with the current `np.set_printoptions()`. For example, with
    np.set_printoptions( threshold=100, edgeitems=3, suppress=True )
only the edges of big `x` and `A` are printed.
`B` is printed as `str(B)`, for any `B` -- a number, a list, a numpy object ...

`printf()` tries to handle too few or too many arguments sensibly,
but this is iffy and subject to change.

How it works:
numpy has a function `np.array2string( A, "%.3g" )` (simplifying a bit).
`printf()` splits the format string, and for format / arg pairs
    format: % d e f g
    arg: try `np.asanyarray()`
-->  %s  np.array2string( arg, format )
Other formats and non-ndarray args are left alone, formatted as usual.

Notes:

`printf( ... end= file= )` are passed on to the python `print()` function.

Only formats `% [optional width . precision] d e f g` are implemented,
not `%(varname)format` .

%d truncates floats, e.g. 0.9 and -0.9 to 0; %.0f rounds, 0.9 to 1 .
%g is the same as %.6g, 6 digits.
%% is a single "%" character.

The function `sprintf()` returns a long string. For example,
    title = sprintf( "%s  m %g  n %g  X %.3g",
                    __file__, m, n, X )
    print( title )
    ...
    pl.title( title )

Module globals:
_fmt = "%.3g"  # default for extra args
_squeeze = np.squeeze  # (n,1) (1,n) -> (n,) print in 1 line not n

See also:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html
http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

'''
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array


#...............................................................................
from __future__ import division, print_function
import re
import numpy as np

__version__ = "2014-02-03 feb denis"

_splitformat = re.compile( r'''(
    %
    (?<! %% )  # not %%
    -? [ \d . ]*  # optional width.precision
    \w
    )''', re.X )
    # ... %3.0f  ... %g  ... %-10s ...
    # -> ['...' '%3.0f' '...' '%g' '...' '%-10s' '...']
    # odd len, first or last may be ""

_fmt = "%.3g"  # default for extra args
_squeeze = np.squeeze  # (n,1) (1,n) -> (n,) print in 1 line not n

#...............................................................................
def printf( format, *args, **kwargs ):
    print( sprintf( format, *args ), **kwargs )  # end= file=

printf.__doc__ = __doc__


def sprintf( format, *args ):
    """ sprintf( "text %.3g text %4.1f ... %s ... ", numpy arrays or ... )
        %[defg] array -> np.array2string( formatter= )
    """
    args = list(args)
    if not isinstance( format, basestring ):
        args = [format] + args
        format = ""

    tf = _splitformat.split( format )  # [ text %e text %f ... ]
    nfmt = len(tf) // 2
    nargs = len(args)
    if nargs < nfmt:
        args += (nfmt - nargs) * ["?arg?"]
    elif nargs > nfmt:
        tf += (nargs - nfmt) * [_fmt, " "]  # default _fmt

    for j, arg in enumerate( args ):
        fmt = tf[ 2*j + 1 ]
        if arg is None \
        or isinstance( arg, basestring ) \
        or (hasattr( arg, "__iter__" ) and len(arg) == 0):
            tf[ 2*j + 1 ] = "%s"  # %f -> %s, not error
            continue
        args[j], isarray = _tonumpyarray(arg)
        if isarray  and fmt[-1] in "defgEFG":
            tf[ 2*j + 1 ] = "%s"
            fmtfunc = (lambda x: fmt % x)
            formatter = dict( float_kind=fmtfunc, int=fmtfunc )
            args[j] = np.array2string( args[j], formatter=formatter )
    try:
        return "".join(tf) % tuple(args)
    except TypeError:  # shouldn't happen
        print( "error: tf %s  types %s" % (tf, map( type, args )))
        raise


def _tonumpyarray( a ):
    """ a, isarray = _tonumpyarray( a )
        ->  scalar, False
            np.asanyarray(a), float or int
            a, False
    """
    a = getattr( a, "value", a )  # cvxpy
    if np.isscalar(a):
        return a, False
    if hasattr( a, "__iter__" )  and len(a) == 0:
        return a, False
    try:
        # map .value ?
        a = np.asanyarray( a )
    except ValueError:
        return a, False
    if hasattr( a, "dtype" )  and a.dtype.kind in "fi":  # complex ?
        if callable( _squeeze ):
            a = _squeeze( a )  # np.squeeze
        return a, True
    else:
        return a, False


#...............................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    n = 5
    seed = 0
        # run this.py n= ...  in sh or ipython
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        exec( arg )
    np.set_printoptions( 1, threshold=4, edgeitems=2, linewidth=80, suppress=True )
    np.random.seed(seed)

    A = np.random.exponential( size=(n,n) ) ** 10
    x = A[0]

    printf( "x: %.3g  \nA: %.1f  \ns: %s  \nB: %s ",
                x,         A,         "str",   A )
    printf( "x %%d: %d", x )
    printf( "x %%.0f: %.0f", x )
    printf( "x %%.1e: %.1e", x )
    printf( "x %%g: %g", x )
    printf( "x %%s uses np printoptions: %s", x )

    printf( "x with default _fmt: ", x )
    printf( "no args" )
    printf( "too few args: %g %g", x )
    printf( x )
    printf( x, x )
    printf( None )
    printf( "[]:", [] )
    printf( "[3]:", [3] )
    printf( np.array( [] ))
    printf( [[]] )  # squeeze
```

Answer (score 9):

And here is what I use, and it's pretty uncomplicated:

```
print(np.vectorize("%.2f".__mod__)(sparse))
```

Answer (score 9):

One can use [`round`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.round.html) method as in `x.round(decimals)` which returns a new numpy array with elements rounded accordingly.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random([5,5])
print(x.round(decimals=3))
```

Comment: This worked for me when passing the array to a matplotlib ylabel, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Was surprised to not see `around` method mentioned - means no messing with print options.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random([5,5])
print(np.around(x,decimals=3))

Output:
[[0.475 0.239 0.183 0.991 0.171]
 [0.231 0.188 0.235 0.335 0.049]
 [0.87  0.212 0.219 0.9   0.3  ]
 [0.628 0.791 0.409 0.5   0.319]
 [0.614 0.84  0.812 0.4   0.307]]
```

Comment: But it does mean creating a second copy of the array each time you want to print it out, which might dissuade some use cases.

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
def np_print(array,fmt="10.5f"):
    print (array.size*("{:"+fmt+"}")).format(*array)
```

It's not difficult to modify it for multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I often want different columns to have different formats.  Here is how I print a simple 2D array using some variety in the formatting by converting (slices of) my NumPy array to a tuple:

```
import numpy as np
dat = np.random.random((10,11))*100  # Array of random values between 0 and 100
print(dat)                           # Lines get truncated and are hard to read
for i in range(10):
    print((4*"%6.2f"+7*"%9.4f") % tuple(dat[i,:]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that the usual float format {:9.5f} works properly -- suppressing small-value e-notations -- when displaying a list or an array using a loop.  But that format sometimes fails to suppress its e-notation when a formatter has several items in a single print statement.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
a3 = 4E-3
a4 = 4E-4
a5 = 4E-5
a6 = 4E-6
a7 = 4E-7
a8 = 4E-8
#--first, display separate numbers-----------
print('Case 3:  a3, a4, a5:             {:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5f}'.format(a3,a4,a5))
print('Case 4:  a3, a4, a5, a6:         {:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5}'.format(a3,a4,a5,a6))
print('Case 5:  a3, a4, a5, a6, a7:     {:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5}{:9.5f}'.format(a3,a4,a5,a6,a7))
print('Case 6:  a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8: {:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5f}{:9.5}{:9.5f}'.format(a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8))
#---second, display a list using a loop----------
myList = [a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8]
print('List 6:  a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8: ', end='')
for x in myList: 
    print('{:9.5f}'.format(x), end='')
print()
#---third, display a numpy array using a loop------------
myArray = np.array(myList)
print('Array 6: a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8: ', end='')
for x in myArray:
    print('{:9.5f}'.format(x), end='')
print()
```

My results show the bug in cases 4, 5, and 6:

```
Case 3:  a3, a4, a5:               0.00400  0.00040  0.00004
Case 4:  a3, a4, a5, a6:           0.00400  0.00040  0.00004    4e-06
Case 5:  a3, a4, a5, a6, a7:       0.00400  0.00040  0.00004    4e-06  0.00000
Case 6:  a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8:   0.00400  0.00040  0.00004  0.00000    4e-07  0.00000
List 6:  a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8:   0.00400  0.00040  0.00004  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
Array 6: a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8:   0.00400  0.00040  0.00004  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
```

I have no explanation for this, and therefore I always use a loop for floating output of multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.char.mod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.mod.html#numpy.core.defchararray.mod) may also be useful, depending on the details of your application e.g.:`numpy.char.mod('Value=%4.2f', numpy.arange(5, 10, 0.1))` will return a string array with elements "Value=5.00", "Value=5.10" etc. (as a somewhat contrived example).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use the `decimal` module:

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import *

arr = np.array([  56.83,  385.3 ,    6.65,  126.63,   85.76,  192.72,  112.81, 10.55])
arr2 = [str(Decimal(i).quantize(Decimal('.01'))) for i in arr]

# ['56.83', '385.30', '6.65', '126.63', '85.76', '192.72', '112.81', '10.55']
```