# Defining precision of floating point number in Python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I have some python code here

Code:

```
 t = 1
 xt = array([ -1.,-1. ])

 xt[0] = theta[0][0]* P_all_States[t-1][0] + theta[1][0]*P_all_States[t-1][1]

 xt[1] = theta[0][1]* P_all_States[t-1][0] + theta[1][1]*P_all_States[t-1][1]

 P_all_States[t][0] = xt[0]
 P_all_States[t][1] = xt[1]
 print ("Added probability distribution for time t = " + str(t) + " to P_all_States")
 print P_all_States
```

Output:

> > Added probability distribution for time t = 1 to P_all_States
> >     [[0.6, 0.4], [0.62000000000000011, 0.38000000000000006], [-1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0]]

How can I get the floating point numbers to round to 2 sigficant digits?

These are all floats, so Im not looking to convert these to strings, I want them to remain as floats

Thanks

Comment: related: [Pretty-printing of numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2891790/4279), namely `np.set_printoptions(precision=2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> round(0.62000000000000011,2)
0.62
```

Comment: You should note that this doesn't actually result in the value `0.62`. `print decimal.Decimal(round(0.62000000000000011,2))` ->
`0.61999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean, but if you mean how you can modify their value to exactly 0.62, etc. : this is not possible with floats, because of their nature. You could use decimals instead of floats to get around this issue.
If you mean how to print the floats with only 2 decimals, use:

```
print '{:3.2f}'.format(somefloat)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the whole list, combine @Zashas answer with:

```
rounded = [ [round(a[0],2), round(a[1],2)] for a in P_all_States ]
```

Comment: it is a list of list, so the above won' t do the job, need something like: rounded = [ [round(a[0],2), round(a[1],2)] for a in P_all_States ]

Comment: sorry - did not realize that. well, you corrected it. thanks!