# How change the float precision of matrix elements (not when viewing)

Tags: python, scipy

I've a matrix with this shape:

```
>>> A = [ [12.11432, 10.00211, 9.44100],[0.12361, 5511.13478, 189.79823] ]
```

A is sparse matrix, I used exactly `lil_matrix`. I want to divide each element of A by the sum of the all elements. The result of this division must be a matrix B with the same precision as A.

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([ [12.11432, 10.00211, 9.44100],[0.12361, 5511.13478, 189.79823] ])
>>> A = lil_matrix(A)
>>> B = A / A.sum()
>>> B.toarray()
array([[  2.11322791e-03,   1.74477296e-03,   1.64689266e-03],
        [  2.15625889e-05,   9.61365048e-01,   3.31084961e-02]])
```

As you can see, the precision between A and B isn't the same.
So, **How can I keep only 5 digit after the decimal point in the B matrix?**

Comment: 1) That's not how floating point numbers work, and 2) You're just looking at the printed representation of the array object

Comment: 3) This seems to be about scipy, not PIL.

Comment: @HocineBen: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array) to see how to change the way Numpy prints arrays, including precision and scientific notation. Does `np.set_printoptions(precision=5, suppress=True); B.toarray()` do what you want?

Comment: @Junuxx: my problem is not in how display my matrix, but I want that my elements in my matrix have exactly the precision = 5

Comment: Maybe you just want `.round(5)` then.

Comment: @nneonneo: How I can do it? can you give a simple code?

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: round not found

Comment: It's `np.round(B,5)`, but I'm not convinced it's very useful to do this. Why do you want this rounding?

Comment: my data is very sensitive, they are cancerous image data.

Comment: I get this error with 'np.round(B,5)': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2295, in round_
    return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: rint

Comment: Strange reason to *reduce* the precision. I think you're on the wrong track. The error is because you try to round a sparse matrix. `np.round(B.toarray(),5)`.

Comment: Let me put it this way: You shouldn't be bothered by the internal representation of a float, *unless* it's **not precise enough** OR because you have so many floats that you would **run out of memory** at the current precision.  *Too precise because your data is very sensitive* makes little sense. You can always present rounded end results by using `np.set_print_options` as I mentioned several comments back.

Comment: @Junuxx: thank you, maybe you're right, I'll keep the precions and when viewing, I'll use np.set_print_options