# Pretty print SciPy array

Tags: python, scipy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[[  9.71369349e+02   1.06915603e+03   1.14821723e+03   3.16300000e+02]
 [  1.83700564e+03   1.85500390e+03   1.87149745e+03   7.69400000e+01]
 ...,
 [  1.00000000e+20   5.56290955e+02   7.92477067e+02   4.34600000e+01]]
```

How can I pretty print this so that the values are not exponentiated?

I've tried using:

`sp.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`

This had no effect.

Comment: What happened exactly? Because it works decently (see e.g. this post for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array).

Comment: The array prints with the same format (as in my example) regardless of  `set_printoptions`.

Comment: I can confirm that `set_printoptions` is working as `sp.set_printoptions(precision=3)` formats correctly, albeit still showing the exponents (`9.713e+02`), which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your code where you set the options and print the array? Also, which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all exponentiation you need to call the `formatter` argument. Modifying the example in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html), something like this should do the trick:

```
sp.set_printoptions(formatter={"float": lambda x: '{:.20f}'.format(x)})
```

This uses [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/string.html) to print a fixed point number(that is the 'f') with 20 decimal places. So `9.71369349e+02` is represented as `971.36934900000005654874`. You will need to decide exactly how to handle this number of decimal places.