# Convert float64 numpy array to floats not in scientific notation

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I currently have a numpy array of float64s:

```
[ -2.75090260e-08   3.11586226e-08   1.86128266e-08  -1.01560789e-07 ]
```

which I would like to print as for an excel spreadsheet import:

```
[ -.0000000275090260   .0000000311586226   .0000000186128266   -.000000101560789 ]
```

I've tried messing about with precision settings, but each number has its own mantissa and exponent.

Note that these output numbers can be considered a string if that makes the process easier, as they are going into a text file for excel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty-printing of numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array)

Comment: If this is for Excel, either format will be treated the same.  To get it to look different in Excel, you have to change the number format there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to print the numbers in decimal format with 16 digits precision? How about this?

```
a = [-2.75090260e-08, 3.11586226e-08, 1.86128266e-08, -1.01560789e-07]
print map(lambda x: "{0:.16f}".format(x), a)
```

This prints

```
['-0.0000000275090260', '0.0000000311586226', '0.0000000186128266', '-0.0000001015607890']
```

**Update:**

You don't even need the lambda. Using

```
map("{0:.16f}".format, a)
```

works just as well. Thanks @JaminSore for pointing that out.

Comment: There's no need for the `lambda`, `map('{0:.16f}'.format, a)` works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you also have the option of:
[numpy.round(_array, _decimalPrecision)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html#numpy-round)