# Format certain floating dataframe columns into percentage in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a paper in IPython notebook, but encountered some issues with display format. Say I have following dataframe `df`, is there any way to format `var1` and `var2` into 2 digit decimals and `var3` into percentages.

```
       var1        var2         var3    
id                                              
0    1.458315    1.500092   -0.005709   
1    1.576704    1.608445   -0.005122    
2    1.629253    1.652577   -0.004754    
3    1.669331    1.685456   -0.003525   
4    1.705139    1.712096   -0.003134   
5    1.740447    1.741961   -0.001223   
6    1.775980    1.770801   -0.001723    
7    1.812037    1.799327   -0.002013    
8    1.853130    1.822982   -0.001396    
9    1.943985    1.868401    0.005732
```

The numbers inside are not multiplied by 100, e.g.  -0.0057=-0.57%.

Comment: In case if anyone is looking at this question after 2014, look at my answer for a concise answer.

Comment: The answers work for immediate formatting, but I was hoping to "attach" the format to the column so that I could continue doing other stuff with the dataframe and it would always print that column in that format (unless I reset the format to something else). Is this possible?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

replace the values using the round function, and format the string representation of the percentage numbers:

```
df['var2'] = pd.Series([round(val, 2) for val in df['var2']], index = df.index)
df['var3'] = pd.Series(["{0:.2f}%".format(val * 100) for val in df['var3']], index = df.index)
```

The round function rounds a floating point number to the number of decimal places provided as second argument to the function.

String formatting allows you to represent the numbers as you wish. You can change the number of decimal places shown by changing the number before the `f`.

p.s. I was not sure if your 'percentage' numbers had already been multiplied by 100. If they have then clearly you will want to change the number of decimals displayed, and remove the hundred multiplication.

Comment: Thanks, will this change the actual values within each column?

Comment: Yes, if that is not desired, then just create new columns with those variables in. As far as I know, there is no way to specify how output appears beyond what the data actually are.

Comment: To round the values in a series you can also just use `df['var2'].round(2)`

Comment: You could also set the default format for float : pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format

Comment: @romain That's a great suggestion (for some use-cases) it should be its own answer (so I can upvote it) Though it does need tweak to multiply by 100.

Comment: as suggested by @linqu, you generally do not want to modify data for display.

Comment: Is there  a way to display a column as percentage without converting it to a string?

Comment: see below answer which is better

Answer (score 206):

The accepted answer suggests to modify the raw data for presentation purposes, something you generally do not want. Imagine you need to make further analyses with these columns and you need the precision you lost with rounding.

You can modify the formatting of individual columns in data frames, in your case:

```
output = df.to_string(formatters={
    'var1': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var2': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var3': '{:,.2%}'.format
})
print(output)
```

For your information `'{:,.2%}'.format(0.214)` yields `21.40%`, so no need for multiplying by 100.

You don't have a nice HTML table anymore but a text representation. If you need to stay with HTML use the `to_html` function instead.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
output = df.to_html(formatters={
    'var1': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var2': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var3': '{:,.2%}'.format
})
display(HTML(output))
```

**Update**

As of pandas 0.17.1, life got easier and we can get a beautiful html table right away:

```
df.style.format({
    'var1': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var2': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var3': '{:,.2%}'.format,
})
```

Comment: If you have n or a variable amount of columns in your dataframe and you want to apply the same formatting across all columns, but you may not know all the  column headers in advance, you don't have to put the formatters in a dictionary, you can do a list and do it creatively like this: output = df.to_html(formatters=n * ['{:,.2%}'.format])

Comment: A standard set of these in a dict with attr access would be great.

Comment: The parts `.format` are not needed, you may omit them.

Comment: `df.style.format({'var3': '{:,.2%}'})` - this is not working. Values remain unchanged i.e. without %

Comment: @zwornik `%` needs to be outside the brackets in `'{:.2f}%'`

Comment: @theFrok Note there's no `f` in `'{:,.2%}'`.  @zwornik Apparently `df.style.format` doesn't change the DataFrame, but IronPython renders the result as HTML. You can use `df.style.format(...).render()` to get the HTML yourself. Or, use `df.apply` directly, which is what happens internally, per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Comment: Is there a way to add this as the default representation of a data frame? I have tried changing `__str__` and  `__repr__` but neither seems to alter the output when putting `df` at the end of my Jupyter/IPython cell.

Comment: still doesn't work `df.style.format({'perc count': '{:,.2}%'})`
Why does this answer have so many upvotes? '%' in or out of the curly bracket...

Comment: Ahhh, figured it out as per one of the comments below : very important, you need to assign a df to the formated df. It is not an option you can set on an existing df.
eg: `df = df.style.format({'perc count': '{:,.2}%'})`

Comment: @GenDemo the output of df.style.format is a Styler object, NOT a DataFrame. Setting it to a variable does not allow you to change any of the underlying DataFrames data values. The Styler object only controls how it is displayed in an output format, e.g. HTML notebook, LaTeX, to string or to Excel.

Answer (score 68):

You could also set the default format for float :

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2%}'.format
```

Use '{:.2%}' instead of '{:.2f}%' - The former converts 0.41 to 41.00% (correctly), the latter to 0.41% (incorrectly)

Comment: Good to know and relevant to OP's question about outputting in an python notebook

Comment: And if the percentages are still given in decimals (e.g. when using `df.pct_change()`): `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2%}'.format`

Comment: of course this would affect all of your dataframes, so you'd have to unset it again to display non-percentage floats.

Comment: As per @fantabolous ' comment, this is not really useful.

Answer (score 43):

Often times we are interested in calculating the full significant digits, but
for the visual aesthetics, we may want  to see only few decimal point when we display the dataframe.

In jupyter-notebook, pandas can utilize the html formatting taking advantage of the method called `style`.

For the case of just seeing two significant digits of some columns, we can use this code snippet:

## Given dataframe

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1.458315, 1.576704, 1.629253, 1.6693310000000001, 1.705139, 1.740447, 1.77598, 1.812037, 1.85313, 1.9439849999999999],
          'var2': [1.500092, 1.6084450000000001, 1.652577, 1.685456, 1.7120959999999998, 1.741961, 1.7708009999999998, 1.7993270000000001, 1.8229819999999999, 1.8684009999999998],
          'var3': [-0.0057090000000000005, -0.005122, -0.0047539999999999995, -0.003525, -0.003134, -0.0012230000000000001, -0.0017230000000000001, -0.002013, -0.001396, 0.005732]})

print(df)
       var1      var2      var3
0  1.458315  1.500092 -0.005709
1  1.576704  1.608445 -0.005122
2  1.629253  1.652577 -0.004754
3  1.669331  1.685456 -0.003525
4  1.705139  1.712096 -0.003134
5  1.740447  1.741961 -0.001223
6  1.775980  1.770801 -0.001723
7  1.812037  1.799327 -0.002013
8  1.853130  1.822982 -0.001396
9  1.943985  1.868401  0.005732
```

## Style to get required format

```py
    df.style.format({'var1': "{:.2f}",'var2': "{:.2f}",'var3': "{:.2%}"})
```

Gives:

```
     var1   var2    var3
id          
0   1.46    1.50    -0.57%
1   1.58    1.61    -0.51%
2   1.63    1.65    -0.48%
3   1.67    1.69    -0.35%
4   1.71    1.71    -0.31%
5   1.74    1.74    -0.12%
6   1.78    1.77    -0.17%
7   1.81    1.80    -0.20%
8   1.85    1.82    -0.14%
9   1.94    1.87    0.57%
```

## Update

If display command is not found try following:

```py
from IPython.display import display

df_style = df.style.format({'var1': "{:.2f}",'var2': "{:.2f}",'var3': "{:.2%}"})

display(df_style)
```

## Requirements

- To use `display` command, you need to have installed Ipython in your machine.
- The `display` command does not work in online python interpreter which do not have `IPyton` installed such as https://repl.it/languages/python3
- The display command works in jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, Google-colab, kaggle-kernels, IBM-watson,Mode-Analytics and many other platforms out of the box, you do not even have to import display from IPython.display

Comment: This is the most Pythonic answer.

Comment: This is a way better answer than the accepted one. Changing the formatting is much preferable to actually changing the underlying values.

Comment: @Poudel This is not working. I have used exacly the same code as yours and var3 is not formatted as percentage

Comment: @zwornik try `display(df.style.format({'var1': "{:.2f}",'var2': "{:.2f}",'var3': "{:.2%}"}))`

Comment: @Poudel It worked now. There is one superflous bracket at the end. It should be:
`df_style = df.style.format({'var1': "{:.2f}",'var2': "{:.2f}",'var3': "{:.2%}"})`
Thanks!

Comment: Had an issue with the index being non unique, so just had to df.reset_index(inplace= True) and then apply the .style.format.  worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: As a fact, When I use this answer, I got the message : `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'head'`

Comment: Ah, very important differentiator here, you need to assign a df to the formated df. It is not simply an option you can set.

Answer (score 28):

As suggested by @linqu you should not change your data for presentation. Since pandas 0.17.1, (conditional) formatting was made easier. Quoting the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html):

> You can apply **conditional formatting**, the visual styling of a `DataFrame` depending on the data within, by using the `DataFrame.style` property. This is a property that returns a `pandas.Styler` object, which has useful methods for formatting and displaying `DataFrames`.

For your example, that would be (the usual table will show up in Jupyter):

```
df.style.format({
    'var1': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var2': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var3': '{:,.2%}'.format,
})
```

Comment: This is not working. I have used exacly the same code as yours

Comment: this will give html output, and be useful for notebooks.
for terminal output, printing to files etc, the `to_string` method is good. It needs pandas version 1.5 or higher.

Answer (score 18):

Just another way of doing it should you *require to do it over a larger range of* columns

**using applymap**

```
df[['var1','var2']] = df[['var1','var2']].applymap("{0:.2f}".format)
df['var3'] = df['var3'].applymap(lambda x: "{0:.2f}%".format(x*100))
```

applymap is useful if you need to apply the function over multiple columns; it's essentially an abbreviation of the below for this specific example:

```
df[['var1','var2']].apply(lambda x: map(lambda x:'{:.2f}%'.format(x),x),axis=1)
```

**Great explanation below of apply, map applymap:**

[Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)

Answer (score 8):

As a similar approach to the accepted answer that might be considered a bit more readable, elegant, and general (YMMV), you can leverage the `map` method:

```
# OP example
df['var3'].map(lambda n: '{:,.2%}'.format(n))

# also works on a series
series_example.map(lambda n: '{:,.2%}'.format(n))
```

Performance-wise, this is pretty close (marginally slower) than the OP solution.

As an aside, if you do choose to go the `pd.options.display.float_format` route, consider using a context manager to handle state per this [parallel numpy example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-printing-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given).

Answer (score 6):

`style.format` is vectorized, so we can simply apply it to the entire `df` (or just its numerical columns):

`df[num_cols].style.format('{:,.3f}%')`

---

Note that if `df` contains only 1 column and is in fact a Series, it will first require conversion to `pandas DataFrame`, e.g. with `pd.DataFrame(df[num_col]).style.format`, or as pointed below: `df[num_col].to_frame().style.format`).

Comment: The series should be converted to data frame first: df[num_cols].to_frame().style.format('{:,.3f}%')

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension has an assured result, I'm using it successfully
I think you may use python list comprehension as follow:

```
df['var1'] = ["{:.2f}".format(i) for i in df['var1'] ]
df['var2'] = ["{:.2f}".format(i) for i in df['var2'] ]
df['var3'] = ["{:.2%}".format(i) for i in df['var3'] ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48792783/5349291) I used the apply function on the given series. In my case, I was interested in showing value_counts for my Series with percentage formatting.

I did:

```
df['my_col'].value_counts(normalize=True).apply(lambda x: "{0:.2f}%".format(x*100))
# Incident             88.16%
# StreetWorks          3.29% 
# Accident             2.36%
# ...
```

Instead of just

```
df['my_col'].value_counts(normalize=True)
# Incident             0.881634
# StreetWorks          0.032856
# Accident             0.023589
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the columns of type `float` should be shown as percentages, you can use a `with statement`:

```
with pd.option_context("display.float_format", "{:.2%}".format):
    display(df)
```

If only specific columns should be formatted as percentages:

```
df.style.format(formatter={c: "{:.2%}" for c in ["column_1", "column_2"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with a correlation matrix:

```
# this matrix has 2 decimals
correlation_matrix = round(numeric_columns.corr(),2)

# but when I Apply a gradient color scheme to the correlation matrix it prints 6 decimals.
styled_matrix = correlation_matrix.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=-1, vmax=1)

# so instead, I need to add this format(precision=2) into the statement as such to format all of the columns with that precision
styled_matrix = correlation_matrix.style.format(precision=2).background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
```