# Problem with style.format() and a decimal column

Tags: python, pandas, format, pandas-styles

I am trying to apply a `style.format` function to a data frame in order to adjust the number of decimal places, since the `round()` function does not apply. (I don't understand why.)

The data in the `df` are of the format `123.0`, `432.0`, and `543.0`, but I need them to have two decimal places (e.g., `123.00`).

I have verified with the function `df.dtypes` that the column is of type `float`.

I tried to apply the following:

```py
import pandas.io.formats.style
import pandas as pd

df['DD'] = df[['Quantity']].style.format("{:.2%}")
df
```

But the following appears in the `DD` field:

```
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f...
```

[image: capture data return]

The `round()` function does not work on the column either.

What can be done?

Comment: Hi @Gonza - I deleted my previous answer because you've changed the question significantly since I first answered. Can you tell us what your python setup is (version #, distribution, juypyterlab/ipython console/python console, etc)? And also, can you explain why you want to round the data? Are you just trying to get the data to display correctly in the python notebook/prompt? Or are you trying to write the data to a file and want the 2-decimal precision to be reflected there? If so, can you post that code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.style` gives back a `Styler` object ([reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)). The `Styler` object can be formatted in different ways. This has not happened in your DD column; you are only halfway through.

You can format the dataframe with

```
df.style.format({'Quantity': "{:.2%}"})
```

as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981601/format-certain-floating-dataframe-columns-into-percentage-in-pandas).