# Showcase the Percent Increase/Percent Change between rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df that shows Dates and Values and I would like to calculate the percent change or percent increase *between rows* - showing the difference between the change from 10/07/2020 to 10/08/2020

```
   Date           Value
    
   10/08/2020     30
   10/07/2020     30
   10/06/2020     30
   10/05/2020     30
   10/04/2020     30
```

Desired Result

```
   Date           Value     PercentIncrease 
    
   10/08/2020     30        0%
   10/07/2020     30        0%
   10/06/2020     30        0%
   10/05/2020     30        0%
   10/04/2020     30        0%
```

This is what I am doing:

```
(df['Delta'] / df['Delta'].shift(1) - 1).fillna(0)
```

Is there a way to show the percent sign too?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175424/3218693) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a string with `%`:

```
df['PctIncrease'] = [f'{x:.2%}' for x in (df['Value'].div(df['Value'].shift(1)) - 1).fillna(0)]
```

Comment: Hi @Quang Hoang, this particular calculation is percent increase as in final - initial/final * 100?

Comment: Yes, probably you want multiplication by `100` as well.

Comment: ok I see @Quang Hoang,  is this showing the percent increase between rows?

Comment: Yes, and there is also `pct_change` function.

Comment: ok yes I am familiar with the percent change ---I am wondering on your code, what does the {x:.2%} mean?