# Setting dataframe style per column doesn't work

Tags: pandas

pandas==1.2.4 and python==3.7

This doesn't change the formatting on column A:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.uniform(0, 1, 9).reshape(3, -1), columns=list('ABC'))
df.style.format({"A": '{:.1f}'})
print(df)
```

This works, however:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].map('{:.1f}'.format)
print(df)
```

So does this:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:.1f}'.format)
print(df)
```

Am I using the feature correctly?

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?bcz `df.style.format({"A": '{:.1f}'})` is working

Comment: I concur, the styling is working for me as well. My question is what are you trying to do with `df` after styling? "styling" the dataframe changes the way data _appears_ not the underlying values while `map` would alter the data in the table. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm just doing `print(df)`. Python==3.7 and pandas==1.2.4

Comment: In a Jupyter notebook or other CSS enabled viewing environment?

Comment: Pycharm console

Comment: See this specific post for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55624414/8076158