# Pandas: change printable representation of series

Tags: python, pandas

Say there is a series/column of three decimal values `s = pd.Series([0.12, 0.1, 0.2])`.

Is it possible to change the way the series prints, while keeping the same underlying data type (in this case float64)? For instance:

```py
# Prints like this
pd.Series(['{:0.0%}'.format(i) for i in s])

0    12%
1    10%
2    20%
dtype: object
```

```py
# Still works as numeric data type
s*2

0    0.48
1    0.40
2    0.80
dtype: float64
```

Is it easy to alter the `__str__` or `__repr__` of this object? Would it be possible to subclass and override this method of `pd.core.series`? Is there a way to make this change work inside of a `pd.DataFrame`?

Edit: Found the answer I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981601/format-certain-floating-dataframe-columns-into-percentage-in-pandas)

Comment: check out the `style` (display) formatting options in the answers in the linked post. pandas has a ton of options for customizing the way a specific dataframe is displayed: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0.12, 0.1, 0.2])

with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:0.0%}'.format):
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:0.0%}'.format)

s = pd.Series([0.12, 0.1, 0.2])

print(s*2)
```

Output:

```
0   24%
1   20%
2   40%
dtype: float64
```