# Error: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray

Tags: python

I am getting an error when running the following program. I am trying to write the output to a file in a disk.

```
import time
start_time = time.clock()

import numpy as np
theta=6
sigma=np.linspace(0,10,80)
Re=np.linspace(5,100,80)

import os
completeName = os.path.abspath("New Volume (F:)/new innings 2/Sigma at 100 @80 .txt")
file = open("Sigma at 100 @80.txt", "w")


for i in np.arange(0,80):
    mu=np.sqrt(Re[i]*sigma)
    A=(mu-1)*np.exp(mu)+(mu+1)*np.exp(-mu)
    B=2*mu*(theta-1)
    C=(A/B)

   D1=np.exp(mu)/2*(mu+sigma)
   D2=np.exp(-mu)/2*(mu-sigma)
   D3=mu**2
   D4=np.exp(-sigma)
   D5=sigma
   D6=mu**2-sigma**2
   D7=D3*D4
   D8=D5*D6
   H=D7/D8
   D9=(1/sigma)
   D=D1-D2+H-D9
   K1=C-D
   K11=np.array(K1)
   print K11
   file.write("%g\n" % K11)

file.close()
print time.clock() - start_time, "seconds"
```

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

corresponding to

```
file.write("%g\n" % K11)
```

Kindly make some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It kind of says right there: %g expects one number, not an entire array. Either loop through it writing each one, or look up Numpy's special fileIO operations

Comment: What don't you understand? The error message tells you exactly the problem; you're passing an `array`, which can't be formatted with `'%g'`.

Comment: I asked here simply because I don't know how to write the entire array to a file. Any suggestion?

Comment: `file.write(' '.join(str(a) for a in K11))`

Comment: Thank you but it writes in indistinguishable form. Can the matrices be arranged in a better way?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty-print a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre)

Comment: Replace the `file.write("%g\n" % K11)` part with `for value in K11: file.write("%g\n" % value)` to handle the `TypeError` error because `K11` is an array NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
file.write("%g\n" % K11)
```

by

```
for j,value in enumerate(K11):
    file.write(f"{value:10.5f}\n")
```

About the specifier `10.5f` , change 5 to any desired value. It sets with how much precision numbers from array are printed. You can use the variable `j` as index.

If I may add a comment, what is the nature of you variable `K1` ? It looks like it is already a float. In that case no need to use array, just print `K1` in the file as a float `file.write(f"{K1:10.5f}\n")`. At each new run of the loop `for i in np.arange(0,80):` you will write the value. Otherwise write each value of `K1` to an array and once the loop is finished print the whole array to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
file.write("%g"*len(K11)+"\n" % tuple(K11))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray indicates that you are trying to write a numpy array to the file as if it were a float. This is happening because K1 (and consequently K11) can be an array if the operations you perform on mu, sigma, and Re result in arrays.

The file.write() method expects a string, so when you are using the %g formatter, it expects a single float value, not an array. If K1 is an array, you need to iterate through it or convert it to a string representation that can be written to a file.

Here's how you can modify your code to fix this error:

```
# Other imports and initial code...

import os
# Use os.path.join for better path handling and compatibility
folder_path = "F:/new innings 2"
file_name = "Sigma at 100 @80.txt"
completeName = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)

# Use 'with' statement to handle file opening and closing automatically
with open(completeName, "w") as file:
    for i in np.arange(0, 80):
        mu = np.sqrt(Re[i] * sigma[i])  # Make sure sigma[i] is used if it's an array
        # ... rest of your calculations

        # If K1 returns a single value, no changes are needed here
        # If K1 is an array, you need to convert it to a string or write each value on a new line
        if isinstance(K1, np.ndarray):
            for item in K1:
                file.write("%g\n" % item)
        else:
            file.write("%g\n" % K1)

# Other code...
```