# The nature of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

As a followup to [my question on mixed types in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27362234/671013):

**Can I think of a `DataFrame` as a list of columns or is it a list of rows?**

In the former case, it means that (optimally) each column has to be homogeneous (type-wise) and different columns can be of different types. The latter case, suggests that each row is type-wise homogeneous.

For the documentation:

> DataFrame is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types.

This implies that a DataFrame is a list of columns.

Does it mean that appending a row to a `DataFrame` is more expensive than appending a column?

Comment: It is probably worth reading this:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe

Comment: The citation I provided is from that link :)

Comment: In that case your thinking about the internal data structures is correct and Joris's answer explains this. Appending a row will be expensive because if the existing memory allocation is insufficient then a new allocation must be made and the contents copied such that it will be a contiguous block of memory for performance reasons

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are fully correct that a DataFrame can be seen as a list of columns, or even more a **(ordered) dictionary of columns** (see [explanation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) here).

Indeed, each column has to be homogeneous of type, and different columns can be of different types. But by using the `object` dtype you can still hold different types of objects in one column (although not recommended apart for eg strings).
To illustrate, if you ask the data types of a DataFrame, you get the dtype for each column:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'int_col':[0,1,2], 'float_col':[0.0,1.1,2.5], 'bool_col':[True, False, True]})

In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]:
bool_col        bool
float_col    float64
int_col        int64
dtype: object
```

Internally, the values are stored as blocks of the same type. Each column, or collection of columns of the same type is stored in a separate array.

And this indeed implies that appending a row is more expensive. In general, appending multiple single rows is not a good idea: better to eg preallocate an empty dataframe to fill, or put the new rows/columns in a list and concat them all at once.
See the note at the end of the [concat/append docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects) (just before the first subsection "Set logic on the other axes").

Comment: Could you make this answer really perfect and add some references to relevant documentations of the discussed issues?

Comment: I added a link for concat/append, but for the internals, I don't think there is any good documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas2/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst#what-is-blockmanager-and-why-does-it-exist here is the design document from the developers of Pandas. From what they say here, DataFrame is indeed implemented column-wise

Answer (score 2):

To address the question: *Is appending a row to a DataFrame is more expensive than appending a column?*
We need to take into account various factors, but the most important one is the internal physical data layout of Pandas Dataframe.

**The short and kind of naive answer**:
If the table(aka DataFrame) is stored in a **column-wise physical layout**, then add or fetch a column is faster than with a row; if the table is stored in a **row-wise physical layout**, it's the other way. In general, the default Pandas DataFrame is stored **column-wise**(but **NOT** all the time). So in general, appending a row to a DataFrame **is indeed** more expensive than appending a column. And you could consider the nature of Pandas DataFrame to be a dict of columns.

**A longer answer**:
Pandas needs to choose a way to arrange the internal layout of a table in memory (such as a Dataframe of 10 rows and 2 columns). The most common two approaches are column-wise and row-wise.

Pandas is built on top of Numpy, and DataFrame and Seires are built on top of Numpy Array. But do notice though Numpy Array is internally stored row-wise in Memory, this is NOT the case for Pandas DataFrame. How DataFrame is stored depends on how it was initiated, cf this post:https://krbnite.github.io/Memory-Efficient-Windowing-of-Time-Series-Data-in-Python-2-NumPy-Arrays-vs-Pandas-DataFrames/

It's actually quite natural that Pandas adopt a column-wise layout most of the time because Pandas was designed to be a data analysis tool that relies more heavily on column-oriented operations than row-oriented operations. cf https://www.stitchdata.com/columnardatabase/

In the end, the answer to the question *Is appending a row to a DataFrame is more expensive than appending a column?* also depends on caching, prefetching etc. Thus it's a rather complicated question to answer and could depend on specific runtime conditions. But the most important factor is the data layout.

---

**Answer from the authors of Pandas**

The authors of Pandas actually mentioned this point in their design documentation. cf https://github.com/pydata/pandas-design/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst#what-is-blockmanager-and-why-does-it-exist

> So, to do anything row oriented on an all-numeric DataFrame, pandas
> would concatenate all of the columns together (using numpy.vstack or
> numpy.hstack) then use array broadcasting or methods like ndarray.sum
> (combined with np.isnan to mind missing data) to carry out certain
> operations.