# Pandas convert float to int if decimals are 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, in which some columns have numeric values while others don't, as shown below:

```
City          a     b       c
Detroit       129   0.54    2,118.00
East          188   0.79    4,624.4712
Houston       154   0.65    3,492.1422
Los Angeles   266   1.00    7,426.00
Miami         26    0.11    792.18
MidWest       56    0.24    772.7813
```

I want to round off these numeric values to 2 decimal places, for which I am using:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

After which df becomes:

```
City          a       b       c
Detroit       129.0  0.54   2,118.0
East          188.0  0.79   4,624.47
Houston       154.0  0.65   3,492.14
Los Angeles   266.0  1.0    7,426.0
Miami         26.0   0.11   792.18
MidWest       56.0   0.24   772.78
```

It works mostly fine, but it also converts proper integers to decimals, i.e., values like 100 are rounded off to 100.0. I want the dataframe like this:

```
City          a       b         c
Detroit       129    0.54      2,118
East          188    0.79      4,624.47
Houston       154    0.65      3,492.14
Los Angeles   266    1         7,426
Miami         26     0.11      792.18
MidWest       56     0.24      772.28
```

I want to keep such values as proper integers itself, while rounding off others to 2 decimal places in all the numeric columns. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362234/mixed-types-of-elements-in-dataframes-column

Comment: @jezrael added sample data

Comment: So original data are strings with `,` for thousands? Or original are floats?

Comment: @jezrael originally data was float but I added commas using df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).applymap('{:,}'.format))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`g format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> General format. For a given precision p >= 1, this rounds the number to p significant digits and then formats the result in either fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its magnitude.
>
> The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the result formatted with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1 would have exponent exp. Then if -4 <= exp < p, the number is formatted with presentation type 'f' and precision p-1-exp. Otherwise, the number is formatted with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1. In both cases insignificant trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it, unless the '#' option is used.
>
> Positive and negative infinity, positive and negative zero, and nans, are formatted as inf, -inf, 0, -0 and nan respectively, regardless of the precision.
>
> A precision of 0 is treated as equivalent to a precision of 1. The default precision is 6.

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).applymap('{:,g}'.format))
print (df)
          City    a     b         c
0      Detroit  129  0.54     2,118
1         East  188  0.79  4,624.47
2      Houston  154  0.65  3,492.14
3  Los Angeles  266     1     7,426
4        Miami   26  0.11    792.18
5      MidWest   56  0.24   772.781
```

Comment: It was giving the column type as float64 after updating all the columns's type coming as an object. I want to update those columns only having 0 after the decimal place as an integer. Could you help me out? I have been trying to do it as all day but couldn't find anything

Comment: @VikasChauhan - Is possible create new question?

Comment: Please explain what the `,` does here.