# Getting rid of the format e+xx in an array of array, Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to get rid of this format to make this file readable in another software.

```
import numpy as np

test=[5.1056e+02, 6.89752e+05, 4.5987126464655e+03]
np.round(test,6)
print(test)

test2=[[5.1056e+02, 6.89752e+05, 4.5987126464655e+03],[5.1056e+02, 6.89752e+05, 4.5987126464655e+03]]
test2=np.array(test2)
np.round(test2,6)
print(test2)
```

1st print gives me :

```
[510.56, 689752.0, 4598.7126464655]
```

2nd print gives me :

```
[[  5.10560000e+02   6.89752000e+05   4.59871265e+03]
 [  5.10560000e+02   6.89752000e+05   4.59871265e+03]]
```

Now the first result would be fine by me, but my data looks like test2. But I still don't understand what the second argument of np.round does, as it is supposed to limit the number of decimals, but I still get 4598.7126464655.
But at least I'd get a usable format.

How can I make this work on something like test2 ?
I tried this :

```
for i in range(np.shape(test2)[0]):
    np.round(test2[i])

print(test2)
```

Still gives me :

```
[[  5.10560000e+02   6.89752000e+05   4.59871265e+03]
 [  5.10560000e+02   6.89752000e+05   4.59871265e+03]]
```

Comment: `np.round(test,6)` does not modify the `test` object itself. It returns a new object. So you have to do `test = np.round(test, 6)`

Answer (score -1):

[4.59871265e+03 is actually equivalent to 4598.71265](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

```
>>> 4.59871265e+03 == 4598.71265
True
```

so your rounding works just fine. [You need to set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array)

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

before printing.

Comment: Nope it doesn't. Looks like it, but it doesn't. OP didn't assign the return value of round.

Comment: Except that even after I made those changes, it doesn't solve my problem of the scientific format e+xx