# Python - Iterating through list of list as a matrix (slice)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, slice

I want to iterate through list of list.
To iterate through every list inside list also.

```
list=[[0.9 0.8 0.1 0.2 0.5 ][0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.7 ][0.6 0.1 0.3 0.2  0.9][0.3 0.7 0.4 0.1 0.8]]
```

Thus to iterate through every list inside, only to the third position, eg:

```
list=[[0.9 0.8 0.1][0.5 0.3 0.2][0.6 0.1 0.3][0.3 0.7 0.4 ]]
```

Somebody tell me, how can do this?
This is my code:

```
list=[]
i=0
j=0
data=open('BDtxt.txt','r')
for line in data.xreadlines():
    lista.append(line.strip().split())
while i<len(lista):
    while j < len(lista[i]):
        print lista[j]
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

and the output is:

```
['0.9', '0.8', '0.1', '0.2', '0.5']
['0.5', '0.3', '0.2', '0.1', '0.7']
['0.6', '0.1', '0.3', '0.2', '0.9']
['0.3', '0.7', '0.4', '0.1', '0.8']
```

and I want the output to be

```
[0.9 0.8 0.1]
[0.5 0.3 0.2]
[0.6 0.1 0.3]
[0.3 0.7 0.4]
```

Comment: Also, please read the Python documentation on looping

Comment: I'm sorry salida is j

Comment: If you just want to print an output slice, use `print(a[:,i:j])`. And if you want more control on output format, see [np.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) and duplicate questions like [Pretty-printing of numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array). There are tons of duplicate questions on all of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called taking a **slice** of an array (not iterating or looping). Use numpy.array. To read in your csv file use either [numpy.genfromtxt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy) or [pandas.read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) - there are tons of duplicate questions on SO for those.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.9,0.8,0.1,0.2,0.5], [0.5,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.7], [0.6,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.9], [0.3,0.7,0.4,0.1,0.8]])

a[:,0:3]
array([[ 0.9,  0.8,  0.1],
       [ 0.5,  0.3,  0.2],
       [ 0.6,  0.1,  0.3],
       [ 0.3,  0.7,  0.4]])
```

Comment: what if numpy is not avaliable?

Comment: @Marcin: install it. numpy and pandas. Make your life easy. If your IT dept  blocks installs, take it up with them. There's really no point in wasting time on a weak native Python rewrite of these superb packages that contain many man-years of work.

Comment: And how can i do it ? if my list inside change of value to two and display something like this:

[0.9 0.8]
[0.5 0.3]
[0.6 0.1]
[0.3 0.7]

Can be iterable?

Comment: Angel, then take the slice `a[:,0:2]`. You can use variables as slice indices e.g. `a[:,i:j]` and run a for-loop over ,ij or whatever. Please read the [numpy Basics of indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) documentation. You can pretty much do anything you might ever want.

Comment: But if you only want to print a slice of the array, no need for nested loops. Just directly do `print(a[:,0:3])`

Comment: And if you want more control on output format, see [np.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) and duplicate questions like [Pretty-printing of numpy.array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-printing-of-numpy-array)

Comment: @smci I have installed numpy and  when i want do a iteration displays a error

Comment: Angel, you need to show us the error message. (Did `import numpy as np` work correctly? Is your PYTHONPATH correct? etc.) And search SO and Google to find the solution.

Comment: smci Can i do something like this?    
i=3   
a[:,0:i]
Further i have to find the min of each list inside but first i need do this

Comment: Well @smci you gave me some ideas, Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! numpy and pandas are brilliant, check them out!

Comment: Hi! @smci I have a trouble, I want to get the minimum of a row
0.9 0.8 0.1  minimum = .1,
0.5 0.3 0.2  minimum = .2, 
0.6 0.1 0.3  minimum = .1,
0.3 0.7 0.4  minimum = .3,

Comment: And my code is this :
import numpy as np
data=np.genfromtxt('BDentrada.txt')
j=0; lista=[]; minimo=0.0; fijo=0;
while j<=3:
 minimo=min(data[:,fijo:j])
 print data
 j+=1


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
But display me a error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    minimo=min(data[:,fijo:j])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @Angel: first make sure the type of entries in `data[]` got read in as integer, not logical or string. Then, Python is telling you it objects to calling min on an array (or array slice). `min(data[:,fijo:j])`. For solution, see these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+min+array . Please read those before opening a new question.