# Local scope for numpy set_printoptions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pretty-print

[np.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) allows to customize the *pretty printing* of numpy arrays. For different use cases, however, I would like to have different printing options.

Ideally, this would be done without having to redefine the whole options each time. I was thinking on using a local scope, something like:

```
with np.set_printoptions(precision=3):
    print my_numpy_array
```

However, `set_printoptions` doesn't seem to support `with` statements, as an error is thrown (`AttributeError: __exit__`). Is there any way of making this work without creating your own pretty printing class? This is, I know that I can create my own Context Manager as:

```
class PrettyPrint():
    def __init__(self, **options):
        self.options = options

    def __enter__(self):
        self.back = np.get_printoptions()
        np.set_printoptions(**self.options)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        np.set_printoptions(**self.back)
```

And use it as:

```
>>> print A
[ 0.29276529 -0.01866612  0.89768998]

>>> with PrettyPrint(precision=3):
        print A
[ 0.293 -0.019  0.898]
```

Is there, however, something more straightforward (preferably already built-in) than creating a new class?

Comment: There is a more compact way to make the context manager, [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2891805/190597).

Comment: @unutbu Didn't know about `contextlib` (nor that answer) thank you! But it still implies defining a new function.. I guess is better than nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 np.array_repr(x, precision=6, suppress_small=True)
```

Or one of the related functions that take keywords like `precision`.   Looks like it can control many, if not all, of the print options.

Comment: Thanks! It is not exactly equivalent to the context manager, but is much more readable (and shorter) for my purposes.

Comment: `np.core.arrayprint.py` is the Python code for all these formatting operations, including the `set_printoptions`.  It was probably written before `contexts` were widely used in Python.

Answer (score 5):

So based on the link given by @unutbu, instead of using

```
with np.set_printoptions(precision=3):
    print (my_numpy_array)
```

we should use:

```
with np.printoptions(precision=3):
    print my_numpy_array
```

which works on my case. If things don't seem changed, try to manipulate other parameters for print options, e.g. `linewidth = 125, edgeitems = 7, threshold = 1000` and so forth.

Comment: Is this thread-safe?