# Problem converting python list to np.array. Process is dropping sting type data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, type-conversion

My goal is to convert this list of strings to a Numpy Array.

I want to convert the first 2 columns to numerical data (integer)

```
list1 = [['380850', '625105', 'Dota 2'],
      ['354804', '846193', "PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS"],
      ['204354', '467109', 'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive']
     ]

dt = np.dtype('i,i,U')
cast_array = np.array([tuple(row) for row in sl], dtype=dt)
print(cast_array)
```

The result is ...

```
[OUT] [(380850, 625105, '') (354804, 846193, '') (204354, 467109, '')]
```

I am losing the string data. I am interested in

1. Understanding why the string data is getting dropped
2. Finding any solution that converts the first 2 columns to integer type in a numpy array

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252197/python-convert-list-to-numpy-array-while-preserving-the-number-formats) gave me the approach but doesn't seem to work for strings

Comment: I agree, you can do it with Pandas. But all I was thinking there may be a performance improvement using the underlying numpy data structures and I am using this as a learning experience / test to see if it can be done this way

Comment: There'll certainly be some performance issues. But, as far as I'm aware, that is also the reason you need to specify the (maximum) string size: using a dynamic string size will lower performance (I guess it makes things more complicated to iterate over under the hood, in C).

Comment: Thank you. Your first comment had the answer. I have posted a solution in case it helps others in the future.

Comment: Arrghhh!! Now I can't slice the array by columns. Which was the main reason for converting in the first place. If I type cast_array[:, 0] I get an error because I have produced an array of tuples rather than a proper 2D np.array

Comment: A proper 2d array can't mix numeric a d string dtypes.  What you get with `dt` is a structured array with fields, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user: 9769953's comment above, this is the solution.

```
#when specifying strings you need to specify the length (derived from longest string in the list)
dtypestr = 'int, int, U' + str(max([len(i[2]) for i in plist1]))

cast_array = np.array([tuple(row) for row in plist1], dtype=dtypestr)

print(np.array(cast_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that at high level is to use pandas, as said in comments, which will silently manage tricky problems :

```
In [64]: df=pd.DataFrame(list1)

In [65]: df2=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')

In [66]: df2
Out[66]: 
        0       1                                 2
0  380850  625105                            Dota 2
1  354804  846193     PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS
2  204354  467109  Counter-Strike: Global Offensive

In [67]: df2.dtypes
Out[67]: 
0     int64
1     int64
2    object
dtype: object
```

`df2.iloc[:,:2].values` will be the numpy array, You can use all numpy accelerations on this part.

Answer (score 0):

Your dtype is not what you expect it to be - you're running into https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8969:

```
>>> dt = np.dtype('i,i,U')
>>> dt
dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<U')])
>>> dt['f2'].itemsize
0  # 0-length strings!
```

You need to either specify a maximum number of characters

```
>>> dt = np.dtype('i,i,16U')
```

Or use an `object` type to store variable length strings:

```
>>> dt = np.dtype('i,i,O')
```