# Why does python numpy std() make unwanted spaces?

Tags: python, numpy

['car3.csv' file download link](http://blogattach.naver.net/9f0a8335221415a38c6c0e3b06e39fe14313ec3b/20171121_33_blogfile/tkdgur946_1511264695731_Odbo04_csv/car3.csv)

```
import csv
num = open('car3.csv')
nums = csv.reader(num)
nums_list = []
for i in nums:
    nums_list.append(i)

import numpy as np
nums_arr = np.array(nums_list, dtype = np.float32)
print(nums_arr)
print(np.std(nums_arr, axis=0))
```

---

The result is this.

---

```
[[ 1.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  5.]
 [ 0.  0.  5.]
 [ 0.  0.  5.]]
[ 0.5         0.5         1.11803401]
```

---

There are lots of spaces that I didn't expected.
How can I handle these anyway?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a spacing problem. What all you need to do is to save the output of the standard deviation. Then, you can access each value like this:

```
 std_arr = np.std(nums_arr, axis=0) # array which holds std of each column

 # now, you can access them by indexing: 
 print(std_arr[0]) # output here is 0.5
 print(std_arr[1]) # output here is 0.5
 print(std_arr[2]) # output here is 1.118034
```

Comment: It can be, but I just want to get them in one list,
like [ 0.5  0.5  1.11803401 ].