# How to print an array using %.2f

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

In the following code I want to print J values upto %.2f. How can I do that?

```
T= np.arange(1,4,1)
J= 1.0/T
print(J)  #[1.  0.5   0.333333  0.25]
print("%.2f" % J)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pretty-printing a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-printing-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like that:

```
T= np.arange(1,4,1)
J= 1.0/T
print(("{:.2f}, "*len(J)).format(*J))
```