# set_printoptions for numpy array doesn't work for numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to use `set_printoptions` from the answer to the question [How to pretty-printing a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-printing-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given)

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_network.py", line 57, in <module>
    output.set_printoptions(precision=3)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_printoptions'
```

Apparently, not all `numpy` arrays are created equal, and what works for a regular `numpy.array` doesn't work for a `numpy.ndarray`.

How can I format a `numpy.ndarray` for priting such as to remove scientific notation?

*UPDATE*

Changing the call to `numpy.set_printoptions()` removes the error, but has no effect on the print format of the ndarray contents.

Comment: `set_printoptions` is a module level function.  It is not a method of an `ndarray`.  What we casually call a `numpy` array is actually an object of class `np.ndarray`.  `np` or `numpy` refers to the module that we import.  There isn't such a thing as a 'regular nupy.array'.

Comment: perhaps my question should be re-worded: How should the module-level function `set_printoptions` be invoked in order to work with an `ndarray`?

Comment: The accepted answer in your link shows how to use `np.set_printoptions`.  Other answers show how to use it in a `context`.  That link also has an answer that use `array2string`.  You'll have to show more code if you want us to diagnose why `numpy.set_printoptions` isn't working for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `numpy.array2string` which takes `ndarray` as input and you can set precision.

Scroll down in below documentation link for examples.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html

Comment: while it would be nice to know why numpy.set_printoptions() doesn't work, this answer does solve my actual problem of printing the array with precision=3

Comment: May be the calling style is little different.... here I found a sample in below repository https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/arrayprint.py  look for "np.set_printoptions"

Comment: you may try something same as said in link (above comment) ..first by setting precision and calling print function with specifying your array is a type of np.array  "print(np.array(output))"

Answer (score -2):

Use suppress = True and may solve the issue:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision = 2, suppress= True)
```