# unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have the array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.2334, 2.3455, 3.456], dtype=np.float32)
```

and want to print:

```
print('{:.2f}%'.format(x))
```

It gives me:

```
unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-printing-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given

Comment: Hmm..The `np.set_printoptions(precision=2)` worked..I was wondering though why the above code doesn't work.

Comment: or as a string  ('{:.2f} %'*len(x)).format(*x)  yields  '1.23 %2.35 %3.46 %'  repeats the format string by the size of x, then starred x unravels to format.

Comment: The `.format` mechanism depends on what's been defined in the object's `__format__` method.  `numpy` developers haven't put much effort into expanding this beyond the basics ('!s' and '!r').  Note that your format string doesn't work for lists either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you still want `format`

```
list(map('{:.2f}%'.format,x))
Out[189]: ['1.23%', '2.35%', '3.46%']
```

Comment: `print("x=" + str(list(map('{:.2f}%'.format,x))))`     

That is, if you want to use "print" and combine text with "+", you must use str().

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x = np.array([1.2334, 2.3455, 3.456], dtype=np.float32)

x= list(map(lambda x :str(x) + '%',x.round(2)))
print(f'{x}')
```

It would print:

```
['1.23%', '2.35%', '3.46%']
```