# Converting Numpy array into list prints out extra zeros? Python

Tags: python, numpy

I made an array using `numpy`, and need to convert each value into a string list.

This is the solution I found that worked :

```
props = np.arange(0.2,0.5,0.1)
props = [str(i) for i in props]
```

However when I print it out this is the result:

```
Out[177]: ['0.2', '0.30000000000000004', '0.4000000000000001']]
```

The result I want is `['0.2', '0.3', '0.4']`.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a more efficient way of doing this or is this a convulated way?

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: 0.30000000000000004.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty-print a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre)

Comment: haha I can't help but laugh that this a question asked by many other programming newbs. Cheers guys!

Comment: @apang maybe you can consider accepting the answer that you found useful so that this question can be closed

Comment: yep, I was trying to accept your answer below but was prompted to wait 4 minutes before doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.around](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html):

```
import numpy as np

props = np.arange(0.2,0.5,0.1)
props = np.around(props, 1)
props = [str(i) for i in props]

#output
['0.2', '0.3', '0.4']
```

Or:

```
props = np.arange(0.2,0.5,0.1)
props = [str(np.around(i, 1)) for i in props]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just round them up

```
props = np.arange(0.2,0.5,0.1)
props = [str(round(i,2)) for i in props]

['0.2', '0.3', '0.4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the `round()`- function you can just use use this little workaround:

```
import numpy as np
props = np.arange(0.2,0.5,0.1)
props = [str(int(i*10)/10) for i in props]
print(props)
```