# Why do the values in the for loop not correspond to those in Numpys arange and linspace?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I simply try to iterate through a sequence, but the values always change slightly, it is only noticeable when you try to save files with the appropriate name. I started with Numpys arange, but since the documentation says that the values can differ if the steps are not integer, I switched to linspace as recommended.

```
import numpy as np
seq = np.linspace(0.01, 0.09,9)
seq2 = ([])
for i in seq:
    seq2.append(i)
```

Seq is:  array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09]) 
Seq2 is: [0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05, 0.060000000000000005,  0.06999999999999999, 0.08,  0.09] 
Could someone explain to me what this issue is about? 
Thanks in advance 
Im working on Python 3.6.7  and Numpy 1.14

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL/DR: Its a display issue with `numpy.ndarray` displaying things differently - you can [customize the printing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
import numpy as np
import sys
np.set_printoptions(precision=20)
seq = np.linspace(0.01, 0.09,9)
print(seq)

[0.01                 0.02                 0.03
 0.04                 0.05                 0.060000000000000005
 0.06999999999999999  0.08                 0.09                ]
```

See [How to pretty-print a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre)

You still got floats inside and "[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)" applies:

```
import numpy as np
seq = np.linspace(0.01, 0.09,9)
seq2 = ([])
for i in seq:
    seq2.append(i)

print(*seq)
print(*seq2)
```

Output:

```
0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.060000000000000005 0.06999999999999999 0.08 0.09
0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.060000000000000005 0.06999999999999999 0.08 0.09
```