# how to force the data type in a numpy array away from scientific notiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using a numpy array to hold data 
the array is holding my date lke this 
 1.2251999e+03 1.2251999e+03 1.2251999e+02
when I would prefer it held is as a floating point

how can I force the array to hold data as I would prefer it where it holds 10. instead of 1.0+01?

thankyou

Comment: Hi, this question seems to have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre

Comment: Scientific notation is a display choice, not a data type issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty-print a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

However, keep that in mind that it is just printing style. Internally, they are all stored in floating point (includes mantissa and exponent) format. Also, note that if the ratio of largest number to smallest number is larger than mantissa size can handle (which I think is around 51 bits), it is going to force scientific notation even with setting `suppress=True`.

sample code:

```
a = np.array([1.234,0.0000002, 1000000])

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
[      1.234           0.0000002 1000000.       ]
```

You can add `floatmode` argument to fill in the blanks with `0`s (it sets different styles of printing float numbers):

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True,floatmode='maxprec_equal')
[     1.2340000      0.0000002 100000.0000000]
```

or

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True,floatmode='fixed')
[     1.23400000      0.00000020 100000.00000000]
```

and if you add precision to it:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True,floatmode='maxprec',precision=2)
[     1.23      0.   100000.  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just the way the output gets printed out, internally, it is most likely represented as a floating point or double precision floating point. If you want to explicitly set the datatype of an array, you can use a named argument `dtype`.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype='float')
```

If you want to control how the data is printed in the terminal, [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre).