# Gensim Word2Vec model floating point

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim

I have trained a word2vec model using gensim. In the models matrix some values' floating point looks like this: "-7.18556e-05"

I need to use the values on the matrix as a string. Is there a way to remove those "e-05","e-04" etc.?

```
import nltk
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

text = "My text is here"
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    sentences[i] = [word for word in sentences[i] if word not in stopwords.words('english')]

model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)

words = model.wv.vocab

for word in words:
    matrix = model.wv[words.keys()]
```

Comment: it is only string displayed by Python - originally it keeps it as float value in memory. Using string formatting you can format it in different way - https://pyformat.info/

Comment: BTW: `print("{:.5f}".format(-7.18556e-05))` gives `-0.00007` and `print("{:.10f}".format(-7.18556e-05))` gives `-0.0000718556`

Comment: While the formatting suggestions will work, why do you ned to use those values as a string? (That exponent-notation is in fact a string, and is understood by Python & many reading-routines, & even many human readers. So knowing specifically the exact purpose of your intended string-representation will allow the right suggestions for formatting – or even identification of situations where the existing representation is more OK than you might think.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that those scientific-notation printouts are valid strings, & will be understood by Python & many reading routines that might be used on your output.

And, when printing for some very specific purpose, there are various formatting options (including the `.format()` options mentioned by comments) to get exactly what you need. (You haven't shown what methods of triggering matrix/array display you're currently using, so it's not clear what suggestions for altering the display, at the key output points, are best.)

But also: all the vectors/matrixes from `gensim` and most similar libraries are typically provided by `numpy`, which has a global setting to alter display options, including a `suppress` parameter for completely stopping such notation. See this other answer for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891805/130288

Ultimately, you may not want to rely on this being set, at some prior time & globally, to get your desired output at one specific intentional place. It'd be clearer, more robust code to explicitly format the results for the purpose. But as a quick fix, the above may fit your need.