# How can .0 decimals be included when working with numpy floats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

I have a numpy array containing mostly whole numbers and floats. The way I understand it, arrays are always stored as floats, and so the integers are stored as <number>.0. I want to work with the entries of this array as whole floats, but after some testing, it seems the whole numbers are printed as <number>. excluding the .0 decimal. I will not be printing these, so np.set_printoptions won't help me. I've also tried adding `'%.1f' %` which works, but isn't a possible solution as it turns my float into a string.

```
verticies = np.array([
    [4.5, 2],
    [0, 1],
    [-1.5, 2], 
    [1.5, 2], 
    [1.5, 1.5], 
    [2, 1.5], 
    [2, -0.5], 
    [1.5, -0.5], 
    [1.5, -2], 
    [0.5, -2], 
    [0.5, -4.5], 
    [-0.5, -4.5], 
    [-0.5, -2], 
    [-1.5, -2], 
    [-1.5, -0.5], 
    [-2, -0.5], 
    [-2, 1.5], 
    [-1.5, 1.5]
])

origin = np.array([
    [verticies[0][0]],
    [verticies[0][1]]
])

print(origin)
```

I would expect this to print `[[4.5], [2.0]]`, but instead it prints `[[4.5] [2. ]]`

In short: how can I include the decimal 0 after 2.?

Any help would be greatly appreaciated!

Comment: If I understand it right, you need a function to modify the output string-cast of your NumPy array, am I right?

Comment: Why can't you use `numpy.set_printoptions` exactly?

Comment: The `2.` is still a float, and it's still exactly `2.0`. Whether or not the 0 is shown in output or string format, doesn't matter for calculations; it only matters to the human eye/mind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty-print a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-pre)

Comment: Nuddel69, When value is 2, you want output of "2.0".  If the value was 2.123, what output desired?

Answer (score 2):

use `np.set_printoptions`

```
float_formatter = "{:.1f}".format
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter})
print(origin)
```

output

```
[[4.5]
[2.0]]
```

Comment: I seem to have misinterpreted my problem. The traceback mentioned being unable to read the value of the array, which lead me to isolating the array in question. I noticed integers being printed on a peculiar form, and assumed this a problem on numpy's part. In the end my problem was a missing datatype identifier! Thank you still, this would've answered my question!